# Set Hosting on PostgreSQL 9.6 for windows 32 bit

Tags: postgresql, networking

From many days i'm trying to set the hosting on my postgreSQL. I try many solution but no one works. The version of my postgres is **9.6 for windows 32 bit** with pgAdmin 4.

I've set in my `pg_hba.conf` with many type of option but non one work. Now it looks like this.

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            @authmethodhost@
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               @authmethodhost@
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 @authmethodhost@
```

I've tried `md5`, `trust`.

the`postgresql.conf` is already set like:

`listen_addresses = '*'`

I don't know how I can obtain the postgresql hosting
(the server work right in local host, the port is right set, the driver is installed).

This is the error message:

```
FATAL: no entry in pg_hba.conf for the guest "MY.IP.AD.DRS",
user "myadmin", "mydatabase" database, SSL is not enabled
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what you mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: Most probably there is a firewall that doesn't allow the listen port on 5432 to be visible from the outside.

Comment: with doesn't work i mean that the server reject the request from the client, the firewall allow the listen port

Comment: Please edit the question and include the following information: What is the connection string you are using? Are you showing the complete `pg_hba.conf` file? Some other hints: Make sure you reloaded the configuration files with `pg_ctl reload` and check the server log to see if that was successful or if there are errors in your file. The string `@authmethodhost@` is a syntax error in `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: i've change the string '@authmethodhost@' with md5 and trust, but the resut is the same. i have reloaded the configuration with 'SELECT pg_reload_conf();'

Comment: a facc ro cazz postgrSQL expert de sta minchla, I ask you to help me, i think you are only able to speack strunz.