# Hosting on PostgreSQL 9.6 for windows 32 bit

Tags: postgresql, hosting

From many days i'm trying to set the hosting on my postgreSQL. I try many solution but no one works. The version of my postgres is 9.6 for windows 32 bit with pgAdmin 4.

I've set in my pg_hba.conf with many type of option but non one work. Now it looks like this.

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            @authmethodhost@
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               @authmethodhost@
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 @authmethodhost@
I've tried md5, trust.
```

the postgresql.conf is already set like:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

I don't know how I can obtain the postgresql hosting (the server work right in local host, the port is right set, the driver is installed).

```
FATAL: no entry in pg_hba.conf for the guest "MY.IP.AD.DRS", 
user "myadmin", "mydatabase" database, SSL is not enabled
```

Thanks.

Comment: The question won't get better if you repeat it. Add new information to the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767152/set-hosting-on-postgrsql-9-6-for-windows-32-bit).

Comment: i'm sorry, if you have read the differences between the first and the second, you'll see the differences, so can you help me, please ?

Comment: I will comment on the original question. This one should be removed. Please always update the original question rather than re-asking it.